# MySQL: Collate in query - any side effects?

Tags: mysql, collation

My `OpenCart` table collation is `utf8_bin`, unfortunately I can't search for product names with accent in their name. I searched on Google and just found that the collation must be `utf8_general_ci` for accent compatible and case insensitive search.

What If I add collate declaration to the search query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `address` 
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Does it have any (bad) side effect? I red about problems with indexing, performance? Or it is totally safe?

Comment: I doubt a simple select statement would have any bad side effects (aside from performance issues with the select statement you're executing). After all, you're not changing the table definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to consider the side effects on query performance, especially those using indexes. Here is a simple test:

```
mysql> create table aaa (a1 varchar(100) collate latin1_general_ci, tot int);
insert into aaa values('test1',3) , ('test2',4), ('test5',5);

mysql> create index aindex on aaa (a1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.59 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc aaa;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a1    | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| tot   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.53 sec)


mysql> explain select * from aaa where a1='test1' ;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+--
----+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | r
ows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+--
----+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | aaa   | ref  | aindex        | aindex | 103     | const |
  1 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+--
----+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.13 sec)

mysql> explain select * from aaa where a1='test1' collate utf8_general_ci;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----
-+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows
 | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----
-+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | aaa   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3
 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----
-+-------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

You can see that MySQL is stopping using the index on a1 when you search it using another collation, which can be a huge problem for you.

To make sure your indexes are being used for queries, you may have to change your column collation to the most frequently used one.

Comment: MySQL is stopping using the index for only this query (in my case search query) or all any other query in the future?

Comment: Only on queries using different collation. If your queries use no (default) collation, I think mysql will still be able to use the indexes.

Answer (score 4):

If practical, change the column definition(s).

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
    MODIFY col VARCHAR(...) COLLATE utf8_general_ci ...;
```

(You should include anything else that was already in the column definition.)  If you have multiple columns to modify, do them all in the same ALTER (for speed).

If, for some reason, you cannot do the `ALTER`, then, yes, you can tweak the `SELECT` to change the collation:

The `SELECT` you mentioned had no `WHERE` clause for filtering, so let me change the test case:

Let's say you have this, which will find only 'San Jose':

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE city = 'San Jose'
```

To include `San José`:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE city COLLATE utf8_general_ci = 'San Jose'
```

If you might have "combining accents", consider using utf8_unicode_ci.  [More on Combining Diacriticals](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#combining_diacriticals) and [More on your topic](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#utf8_collations_examples).

As for side effects?  None except for on potentially big one:  The index on the column cannot be used.  In my second `SELECT` (above), `INDEX(city)` is useless.  The `ALTER` avoids this performance penalty on the `SELECT`, but the one-time `ALTER`, itself, is costly.

Answer (score 2):

In [using of COLLATE in SQL statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html), I don't find that usage, Anyway for explaining about your main question of effects of using collations I found some tips, but at first:

From *dev.mysql.com*:

> Nonbinary strings (as stored in the `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, and `TEXT` data types) have a character set and collation. A given character set can have several collations, each of which defines a *particular sorting* and *comparison order* for the characters in the set.

1. Collation is merely the ordering that is used for string comparisons—it has (almost) nothing to do with the character encoding that is used for data storage. I say almost because collations can only be used with certain character sets, so changing collation may force a change in the character encoding.
   To the extent that the character encoding is modified, MySQL will correctly re-encode values to the new character set whether going from single to multi-byte or vice-versa. Beware that any values that become too large for the column will be truncated.<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950380/4519059)</sup>
2. The practical advantage of binary collation is its speed, as string comparison is very simple/fast. In general case, indexes with binary might not produce expected results for sort, however for exact matches they can be useful.<sup>[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533763/4519059)</sup>
3. With multiple operands, there can be ambiguity. For example:

   ```
   SELECT x FROM T WHERE x = 'Y';
   ```

   Should the comparison use the collation of the column `x`, or of the string literal `'Y'`? Both `x` and `'Y'` have collations, so which collation takes precedence?
   Standard SQL resolves such questions using what used to be called **“coercibility”** rules. <sup>[[3]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-expressions.html)</sup>
4. If you change the collation of a field, `ORDER BY` -[also in `WHERE`]- cannot use any `INDEX`; hence it could be surprisingly inefficient. <sup>[[4]](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll)</sup>
5. Since the forced collation is defined over the same character set as the column's encoding, there won't be any performance impact(versus defining that collation as the column's default; whereas `utf8_general_ci` will almost certainly perform slower in comparisons than `utf8_bin` due the extra lookups/computation required).
   However, if one forced a collation that is defined over a different character set, MySQL would have to transcode the column's values (which would have a performance impact).<sup>[[5]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45777/60970)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [UTF-8: General? Bin? Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode)
Please note that `utf8_bin` is also case sensitive. So I would go for altering table collation to `utf8_general_ci` and have peace of mind for the future.